# validate JSON object received from php

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

i am using an ajax call to receive data from server, now i have a data in the form of associative array in php first let me show you the format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] =>  Nuts 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 44
            [name] => Dried Fruits 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 73
            [name] => Chocolate Products
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 83
            [name] => Seeds and Grains
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 91
            [name] => Speciality Mixes 
        )

)
```

now to use it in javascript i have to convert it into **JSON** here is my php code so far

```
public function ajax_step1(){
    $data=$this->Step->step1();
    //print_r($data) /returns the array/
    echo json_encode($data);
    //prints the json object
}
```

this is how php is returning the json object!

```
[{"id":"1","name":" Nuts "},{"id":"44","name":"Dried Fruits "},{"id":"73","name":"Chocolate Products"},{"id":"83","name":"Seeds and Grains"},{"id":"91","name":"Speciality Mixes "}]
```

now when i try to use the data in javascript it is giving me this error!

this error is shown by mozilla

**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data**

this error is shown by chrome

**Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**

here is the javascript code:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>Admin/ajax_step1',
         dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
        JSON.parse(data);

        for($i=0;$i<data.length;$i++){
            console.log(data[$i]['name']);
        }

        }
    });
```

here is a little debugging i did for javascript!

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '<?=base_url()?>Admin/ajax_step1',
         dataType:"json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
           //this is returning an array like
            //Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]
        console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        //this is where the error is occuring


        }
    });
```

Comment: your json is valid, problem is elsewhere.

Comment: The JSON you posted is valid. Your problem is most probably with your JavaScript code.

Comment: where? and why the downvote? i tried to be as concise as i  could

Comment: `JSON.parse` is for parsing JSON, which is a string. You have a JavaScript array filled with objects, which doesn't need to be parsed.

Comment: that was totally my fault! i updated the code please have a look.

Comment: you need to show your javascript code which is dealing with this json data

Comment: `console.log(data)` before you try to parse it, and post the results.

Comment: Sometimes you miss that you also did echo to some debug or you also get some PHP warning with the answer, best option is to look at the answer you get before you parse it

Comment: i debugged it a little seems the error is on parsing